# MDX ParallelPeriod, show the actual date

Tags: ssas, mdx

I use `ParallelPeriod`. It works fine to show some measures from last year like this:

```
member [Measures].[ParallelPeriodLastYear1] As
 ( 
     [Measures].[MeasureSomething] 
   , ParallelPeriod( 
        [DimBookingDate].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Year]
       , 1 
     ) 
 )
```

But I also want to return as field the actual result from `ParallelPeriod`, this is the date which was last year. So if my current DimBookingDate member is 2016-03-01, I want to get a field which tells 2015-03-01. How can I do this?

This produces an error:

```
member [Measures].[ParallelPeriodLastYear1] As
  ( 
        [DimBookingDate].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].currentmember 
      , ParallelPeriod( 
          [DimBookingDate].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Year]
         ,1 
        ) 
  )
```

And this produces Null:

```
member [Measures].[ParallelPeriodLastYear1] As
   ParallelPeriod( [DimBookingDate].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Year],1 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the definition Parallelperiod returns a *member* so you should be able to return it's caption as a measure:

```
member [Measures].[ParallelPeriodLastYear1] As
   ParallelPeriod( 
       [DimBookingDate].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Year]
      ,1 
   ).item(0).member_caption
```

Definition of function and its return type is here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145500.aspx

Comment: @Mike can you click the checkmark to mark the answer please?

Comment: @GregGalloway Thanks - this is one of the unfortunate downsides of SO ... shame that moderators cannot be given powers to clean up this slight glitch in their system: I'm sure it has been discussed on the Meta site.